# getting the primary key from a bindingsource save in c sharp

Tags: c#, datatable, bindingnavigator

I am using VS Express 2012 and SQL Express (localdb).

My question is in 2 parts but is based around the same function that I want.

1) in the save button of my bindingNavigator is the following code

```
this.Validate();
this.bsS24s.EndEdit();
this.tamS24s.UpdateAll(this.dsS24s);
```

I want to be able to interject another value into the datatable field that isn't bound to a form object. So from this form, field `source_id` should always = 1 (from another form it may be 2 etc.)
How do I do that?

2) Once this row is saved (a new row), how do I get back the primary key? As I need to save some related data into another database table via a direct connection using SQL.

Many Thanks

Comment: What kind of object is `tamS24s`?  Also, I infer that `source_id` identifies what form provided the record?

Comment: Ah yes, tamS24s is a table adapter manager. Also I meant source_id is a field in the datatable. I just had a field on the form to try and bind it but I couldn't. If I can pass the value of "1" directly to it before it saves that would be cool.

Comment: Done 2)! Actually just 2 lines. DataRow dr = (bsS24s.Current as DataRowView).Row; then get dr["id"]